# passing parameters to a stored procedure through SQL Alchemy using session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that is expecting 3 arguments such has:

```
prices__get 
@cusip varchar(max),
@start_date date = null,
@end_date date = null
```

I am trying to call it using the session.execute like:

```
session.execute('prices__get @cusip=?, @start_date=?, @end_date=?', {cusip:'X23939', start_date:None, end_date:None})
```

also tried:

```
session.execute('prices__get ?,?,?', ['x23939', None,None])
```

is there anyway to call a stored proc using session?

thanks

Comment: I've no idea about SQL Server stored proc syntax etc. (though are you missing EXEC there?), but your first attempt would fail because you're trying to mix positional and named placeholders. To make the 1st attempt work wrap the SQL statement in `text()` and use the `:name` style placeholders: `session.execute(text('prices__get @cusip=:cusip, @start_date=:start_date, @end_date=:end_date'), { 'cusip': 'X23939', 'start_date': None, 'end_date': None })`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for the help, I tried both. with text and trying exec in front of the stored proc. both did not work. `NameError: name 'cusip' is not defined` is always raise

Comment: That's your original attempt at creating the dictionary acting up, unless you fixed that as well. Instead of `{ cusip: 'X2...' }`, which is trying to access the object bound to name `cusip` as key do `{ "cusip": "X2..." }`, which will use the string "cusip" as key. Or in other words, Python's not Javascript.